# Move pages with similar name within workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to finish a macro that selects all worksheets with similar names and moves them before a certain sheet in a workbook.  The user can add as many pages with these names so i couldn't just use an array function to move them. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Copier()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim x As Integer
x = InputBox("Enter Number of Additional Features")
For numtimes = 1 To x
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Data Collection", "Findings", "Visual Findings")).Copy _
Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final Results")
  'Allows user to create as many pages as necessary

Dim ws As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If (ws.Name) Like "*Data Collection*" Then
        ws.Select Not flg
        flg = True
 End If
 Next
'Selects all sheets for "Data Collection"
'Now I need to move all of those selected before a certain sheet at the 
  beginning of the workbook
'I cant seperate the copy functions because some formulas from data collection have to carry 
over to the other copied sheets

'Sheet2.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you define "Similar name"?  "Findings" similar to "Visual Findings"?  Perhaps it might be better stated that you want a certain page ("Final Results"?) *after* all other sheets?

Comment: The data collection pages created by the user needs to go near the beginning of the report.  There are other pages before and after the created pages not tied to this.  I am trying to direct all of the data collection pages to the beginning so my users can fill them out without having to go through the whole report.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
Dim sheetNames As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*Data Collection*" Then sheetNames = sheetNames & "|"
Next

If sheetNames <>"" Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Split(Left(sheetNames, Len(sheetNames) - 1),"|").Move Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final Results")
```

Comment: I figured it out going another direction:

Comment: Dim numtimes As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As String
    x = InputBox("Enter Number of Additional Features")
    For numtimes = 1 To x
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Data Collection", "ILI vs NDE",       "Screen Shot")).Copy _
    Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MPI")

    If numtimes > 1 Then
    y = "Data Collection (" & numtimes & ")"
    Else: y = "Data Collection"
    End If

    Worksheets("Data Collection (" & numtimes + 1 & ")").Move _
    After:=Worksheets(y)